# 0 byte file created in a simple script

Tags: bash, shell, test

I have a script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
df -k | tr -s " " "," | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1,$5}'|sed 1d > file1.txt
while read partition percentUsed
do
if [ $percentUsed > 75 ]
then
echo Partition: ${partition} space is ${percentUsed}
else
echo Pration: $partition: OK!!
fi
done < file1.txt
```

The script is executing properly, however, it is creating a zero byte file by the name 75. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
$ sh diskUsed.sh
Partition: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN/bin space is 75%
Partition: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN/lib space is 75%
Partition: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN space is 75%
Partition: C: space is 75%
Partition: H: space is 91%


$ ls -lrt
total 2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 diwvibh Domain Users 284 Nov 21 04:17 diskUsed.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 diwvibh Domain Users 133 Nov 21 04:29 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 diwvibh Domain Users   0 Nov 21 04:29 75
```

Comment: Why do you give the file a shebang line with `bash` and than run the file through `sh` (which could be some other file) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if [ $percentUsed > 75 ]
```

You should use the **-gt** operator for numeric comparisons; what you are doing is saving the (empty) output of the command "**[ $percentUsed ]**" into a file named "75".

> The script is executing properly, however, it is creating a zero byte
>   file by the name 75. Any ideas why this is happening?

It is not executing properly. The "**[ $percentUsed ]**" command returns true if the string is non-empty, which it always is for this script, so it will *always* take the first branch of the if statement.

Because **$percentUsed** is not an integer (it has a trailing '%') could use **${percentUsed%[%]}** to remove the trailing '%' from the variable, or add zero inside awk, as @val0x00ff suggests.

General comments for bash scripts:

1. Favor [[ *expr* ]] rather than [ *expr* ] as it is more powerful and handles empty strings better.
2. Use double quotes around strings unless you have reason not to do so, eg: getting rid of newlines.
3. Add braces: ${var} rather than $var -- it can often eliminate confusion when reading and allows variables to abut text, like: **echo "Remaining: ${kb}KB"**
4. Generally, avoid creating temporary files when possible. Use pipes between stages instead.
5. If you're using a tool (like *awk*) then learn how to use its power, it will make your code more concise and make it easier to read others' code.
6. Indent your code properly (which perhaps you did in reality but not in the post).
7. If you plan to type exclamation marks ("!"), the use **set +H** so they don't screw up your *interactive* bash by inserting history.

Here is a working version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash +H
df -k | awk '(FNR>1){print $1,$5+0}' | while read partition percentUsed
do
    if [[ $percentUsed -gt 75 ]]
    then
        echo "Partition: ${partition} space is ${percentUsed}% used"
    else
        echo "Partition: ${partition}: OK!!"
    fi
done
```

Nit pick: your "echo" line would output "Partition /home space is 80" if it was 80% used, many would read "space" as "*free* space" which would be 20%.

Answer (score 2):

In line 5 you write the contents of $percentUsed to file "75". Instead, try ``` if [ ``echo $percentUsed | sed 's/%//'`` -gt 75 ] ``` which should do what you desire. At least with bash 4.2.25 on Linux it works. Note: Please only use one backtick instead of two shown here - that's because the Stackexchange web platform interprets those backticks.

Comment: I tried both, even with "75" it creates a file. when -gt is used, i get the below error:  diskUsed.sh: line 6: [: 75%: integer expression expected
Pration: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN/bin: OK!!
diskUsed.sh: line 6: [: 75%: integer expression expected
Pration: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN/lib: OK!!
diskUsed.sh: line 6: [: 75%: integer expression expected
Pration: C:/Users/Public/Documents/CYGWIN: OK!!
diskUsed.sh: line 6: [: 75%: integer expression expected
Pration: C:: OK!!
diskUsed.sh: line 6: [: 91%: integer expression expected
Pration: H:: OK!!

Comment: @user80040 Does writing "if (( percent > 75 ))" as suggested by val0x00ff work accordingly?

Comment: @MichaelKremser I don't think that will work the way how he dumped the output to `file1.txt`. This file will include `%` in the second field.  `while read ... percentUsed` will have `%` sign in there and will never be compared.

Comment: What gets written to the file is not the content of the variable, it's the output of the command `[ $percentUsed ]`, which is empty.

Comment: @val0x00ff: Thanks! I have overseen that. I improved my answer based on your valuable feedback. Also, I tried it out on my machine and here it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is one efficient way to calculate the disk space. In this example, I am using the `/home` dir.

```
#!/bin/bash

 { read -r; read -rd '' -a disk_usage; } < <(LC_ALL=C df -Pk "/home"; printf \\0)
    percent=$(echo "${disk_usage[4]}" | awk '{print $0+0}')
    if (( percent > 75 )); then echo "Disk is critical"; else echo "Disk space is OK"; fi
```

As a side note, The command you have there which is

```
df -k | tr -s " " "," | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1,$5}'|sed 1d
```

Is very inefficient since it forks a lot of processes like `tr`, `awk`, `sed`. You can do this in one go. Remove the `+0` at the end if you want to see the `%` sign.

```
df -k | awk 'NR>1{print $1,$(NF-1)+0}'
```